# how to use the same vscode remote Python terminal on a different computer?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode in the remote mode. on computer A when I select "run selection in Python terminal" it automatically opens up a Python terminal X; when I open the same project on a different computer B I can still see the same Python terminal X, however, when I try "run selection in Python terminal" it opens up a new Python terminal Y. Is it possible to tell VSCode to still use terminal X on computer B? it'll be much convenient to pick up everything in the same terminal than start everything all over again in a new terminal.

Comment: Doubtful. The "run python" action will run a new subprocess Python interpreter. Not "attach" to an existing shell process. Particularly, to prevent remote code execution. If this is what you want, try using Jupyter Server with single-user kernel mode.